# How to split multiple select statements into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a way to split multiple `SELECT` statements into columns. Let me demonstrate what I mean with an example. Say I have these two statements:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableA;` and `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableB`.

How can I, in the same query, put the `COUNT`s into two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableA) AS count1, 
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableB) AS count2
```